# Counts of Rows : (SOME IF CONDITION)+(SOME IF CONDITION) this is the requirement DEX Power BI calculation field

Tags: powerbi

[image]

Here I am putting the formula:

```
Calculate(Count(IF([Condition Type]= "ZMAN" && ([Condition Status] = "Inactive",1))+Count(IF([Condition Type]= "PR00" && ([Condition Status] = "Active",1)) )
```

Comment: Measure1 = IF( (data[Condition Status]="Active"||data[Condition Type]="ZAMAN") && (data[Condition Status]="Inactive"||data[Condition Type]="PROO"),"ZAMAN OVER PROO"])

Another try also gives error..please help

Comment: What exactly you need what is your criteria for a measure??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work, splitted in three measures. You dont use `IF` in Power BI, you use `FILTER`:

```
Count PROO = Calculate(Count([Condition Type]), Filter('YourTable', 'YourTable'[Condition Type] = "PROO" && 'YourTable'[Condition Status] = "Active"))

Count ZMAN = Calculate(Count([Condition Type]), Filter('YourTable', 'YourTable'[Condition Type] = "ZMAN" && 'YourTable'[Condition Status] = "Inactive"))

Overall Count = [Count PROO] + [Count ZMAN]
```